# AWS Lambda and SQL Server Integration with node.js code

Tags: node.js, sql-server, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

**Can you please tell me, I am getting connect error by using this code**

> aws lambda - connect to mssql with nodejs

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
sql.connect({
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    server: 'xxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com',
    database: 'xxxxx',
    port: 1433,
},
    err => {
        // ... error checks
        if (err) {
            callback('connect failed', err);
        } else {
            callback(null,'connected');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What have you checked or tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

exports.handler = async event => {
  try {
    await sql.connect('mssql://username:password@server:port/database');
    return 'connected';

  } catch (err) {
    console.error('cannot connect', err.message);
  }
  return 'connect failed';
}
```

Execute the lambda and check out the CloudWatch log, if you see an error.

Comment: the code is ok but when I host this code in awslambda every time it's showing connect failed `START RequestId: 25eb1c7b-79d4-4dbd-b869-03d167e08190 Version: $LATEST
2019-03-14T08:59:33.556Z 25eb1c7b-79d4-4dbd-b869-03d167e08190 cannot connect Failed to connect to xxxxxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 in 15000ms
END RequestId: 25eb1c7b-79d4-4dbd-b869-03d167e08190
REPORT RequestId: 25eb1c7b-79d4-4dbd-b869-03d167e08190 Duration: 15525.80 ms Billed Duration: 15600 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 47 MB `

Comment: I also have the exact same error, and have tried iam policies and security groups. Lambda code runs successfully against the same db running lambda locally, but not as deployed function.